# Problems with SQL Server 2012 on a Windows 2008 R2 Core Server

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, sql-server-2012, webdeploy

Created a script that installs an empty server to a server that uses an SQL Db, IIS, WebDeploy and FTP. Everything installs but when i try to run my createsqldatabaseb.ps1 it gives an error. Been searching a solution for about two weeks by now. 
I've included a screenshot, ConfigurationFile.ini that setup.exe uses(SQL Server installer) and my script.

I'm looking for a small configuration error that prevents me from creating the Database.

Thanks.

[Error that command gives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrmLu.png)

A couple of dism action to enable powershell etc...

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx2-ServerCore
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3-ServerCore
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx2-ServerCore-WOW64
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3-ServerCore-WOW64
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:MicrosoftWindowsPowerShell-WOW64
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:ServerManager-PSH-Cmdlets

powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
powershell ./InstallIIS.ps1
```

CnfigurationFile.ini

```
    ;SQL Server 2012 Configuration File
[OPTIONS]

; Specifies a Setup work flow, like INSTALL, UNINSTALL, or UPGRADE. This is a required parameter. 

ACTION="Install"

; Detailed help for command line argument ENU has not been defined yet. 

ENU="True"

; Setup will not display any user interface. 

QUIET="False"
IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True"
; Setup will display progress only, without any user interaction. 

QUIETSIMPLE="True"

; Specify whether SQL Server Setup should discover and include product updates. The valid values are True and False or 1 and 0. By default SQL Server Setup will include updates that are found. 

UpdateEnabled="True"

; Specifies features to install, uninstall, or upgrade. The list of top-level features include SQL, AS, RS, IS, MDS, and Tools. The SQL feature will install the Database Engine, Replication, Full-Text, and Data Quality Services (DQS) server. The Tools feature will install Management Tools, Books online components, SQL Server Data Tools, and other shared components. 

FEATURES=SQLENGINE,CONN,FULLTEXT

; Specify the location where SQL Server Setup will obtain product updates. The valid values are "MU" to search Microsoft Update, a valid folder path, a relative path such as .\MyUpdates or a UNC share. By default SQL Server Setup will search Microsoft Update or a Windows Update service through the Window Server Update Services. 

UpdateSource="MU"

; Displays the command line parameters usage 

HELP="False"

; Specifies that the detailed Setup log should be piped to the console. 

INDICATEPROGRESS="False"

; Specifies that Setup should install into WOW64. This command line argument is not supported on an IA64 or a 32-bit system. 

X86="False"

; Specify the root installation directory for shared components.  This directory remains unchanged after shared components are already installed. 

INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify the root installation directory for the WOW64 shared components.  This directory remains unchanged after WOW64 shared components are already installed. 

INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify a default or named instance. MSSQLSERVER is the default instance for non-Express editions and SQLExpress for Express editions. This parameter is required when installing the SQL Server Database Engine (SQL), Analysis Services (AS), or Reporting Services (RS). 

INSTANCENAME="MSSQLSERVER"

; Specify that SQL Server feature usage data can be collected and sent to Microsoft. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable this feature. 

SQMREPORTING="False"

; Specify the Instance ID for the SQL Server features you have specified. SQL Server directory structure, registry structure, and service names will incorporate the instance ID of the SQL Server instance. 

INSTANCEID="MSSQLSERVER"

; Specify if errors can be reported to Microsoft to improve future SQL Server releases. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable this feature. 

ERRORREPORTING="False"

; Specify the installation directory. 

INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Agent account name 

AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT"

; Auto-start service after installation.  

AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; CM brick TCP communication port 

COMMFABRICPORT="0"

; How matrix will use private networks 

COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL="0"

; How inter brick communication will be protected 

COMMFABRICENCRYPTION="0"

; TCP port used by the CM brick 

MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT="0"

; Startup type for the SQL Server service. 

SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Level to enable FILESTREAM feature at (0, 1, 2 or 3). 

FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"

; Set to "1" to enable RANU for SQL Server Express. 

ENABLERANU="False"

; Specifies a Windows collation or an SQL collation to use for the Database Engine. 

SQLCOLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"

; Account for SQL Server service: Domain\User or system account. 

SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQLSERVER"

; Windows account(s) to provision as SQL Server system administrators. 

SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=".\Administrator"

; The default is Windows Authentication. Use "SQL" for Mixed Mode Authentication. 

SECURITYMODE="SQL"
SAPWD="Opleelan8"

; Provision current user as a Database Engine system administrator for SQL Server 2012 Express. 

ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="False"

; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the TCP/IP protocol. 

TCPENABLED="1"

; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the Named Pipes protocol. 

NPENABLED="1"

; Startup type for Browser Service. 

BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
```

My Install script

```
    #Importeer ServerManager
Import-Module ServerManager

#Install IIS
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature

#Installeer .Net-Framework
Add-WindowsFeature net-Framework

#Importeer WebAdministration & Web-Mgmt-Service
Import-Module WebAdministration

#Installeer Web-Mgmt-Service
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Service

#Installeer .NET 4
./dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64_SC.exe
write-host ".NET installed"

# Install Web Deploy
Write-Host "Installing Web Deploy"
.\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL /qn
Write-Host "INSTALLED Web Deploy"

# Install Microsoft® Core XML Services, needed for SMO
Write-Host "Installing Microsoft Core XML SERVICES"
.\msxml6_x64.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL /qn
Write-Host "Installed Microsoft Core XML SERVICES"

#Install CLR Types
Write-Host "Installing CLR TYPES"
.\SQLSysClrTypes.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL /qn
Write-Host "Installed CLR TYPES"

# Install MS SQL Server Management Objects.
Write-Host "Installing MS SQL Server Management Objects"
./SharedManagementObjects.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL /qn
Write-Host "Installed MS SQL Server Management Objects"

#Install SQL SERVER
Write-Host "Installing SQL SERVER"
.\setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=ConfigurationFile.ini
Write-Host "INSTALLED SQL SERVER"

Clear-Host
$teamnaam = "ErosRammazani"
$teampass = "Opleelan8"
$sitePort="8007"
$sqlServerInstanceName="MSSQLSERVER"
$sqlServerName=$sqlServerInstanceName
$databaseAdminUser="sa"
$databaseAdminPassword="Opleelan8"
$Sitedir="C:\inetpub"
$Settingsdir="C:\inetprofiles"
$Scriptdir="C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\Scripts"
$AppCmd="C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe"
# .NET toegang geven tot databank
$aspnet="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe"
# Path tests
Set-Location -Path "$Scriptdir"
if (!(Test-Path -path $Sitedir)) {New-Item $Sitedir -Type Directory}
if (!(Test-Path -path $Settingsdir)) {New-Item $Settingsdir -Type Directory}
if (!(Test-Path ".\SetupSiteForPublish.ps1"))
{ Write-Host -NoNewline "Installeer Wdeploy.exe"; Exit 1 }

##################### User per team aanmaken
net user $teamnaam $teampass /add /passwordchg:no /expires:never /active:yes /fullname:$teamnaam /comment:$teamnaam
# Set the FTP user account’s password not to expire
$WMI = gwmi win32_useraccount | where {$_.name -eq $teamnaam}
$WMI.PasswordExpires = $False
$WMI.put()

###################### Site publiceren in IIS . Elk team een eigen App Pool
Write-Host -NoNewline "publiceren site $teamnaam"
$siteName=$teamnaam
$sitePhysicalPath=$Sitedir+"\"+$siteName
$siteAppPoolName=$teamnaam+"AppPool"
$deploymentUserName=$teamnaam
$deploymentUserPassword=$teampass
$managedRunTimeVersion="v4.0"
.\SetupSiteForPublish.ps1 -siteName $siteName -sitePhysicalPath $sitePhysicalPath -siteAppPoolName $siteAppPoolName -sitePort $sitePort -deploymentUserName $deploymentUserName -deploymentUserPassword $deploymentUserPassword -publishSettingSavePath $Settingsdir -publishSettingFileName $siteName".PublishSettings" -managedRunTimeVersion $managedRunTimeVersion

################### SQL db aanmaken
Write-Host -NoNewline "SQL db aanmaken voor $teamnaam"
$databaseName="db$teamnaam"
$databaseUserName="dbuser$teamnaam"
$databaseUserPassword=$teampass
Set-Location -Path "$Scriptdir"
.\CreateSqlDatabase.ps1 -databaseName $databaseName -databaseUserName $databaseUserName -databaseUserPassword $databaseUserPassword -databaseAdminUser $databaseAdminUser -databaseAdminPassword $databaseAdminPassword -sqlServerInstanceName $sqlServerInstanceName -publishSettingSavePath $Settingsdir -publishSettingFileName $databaseName".PublishSettings"

#################### Default pagina klaarzetten op de site
echo "<html><body><h2>Default pagina $teamnaam</h2><p><%Response.Write(now())
%></p></body></html>" | Out-File $sitePhysicalPath\default.aspx

# Virtuele dir op default website
& $appcmd ADD vdir /app.name:"Default Web Site/" /path:/$teamnaam /physicalPath:C:\$Sitedir\$teamnaam

# .NET toegang geven tot databank
# -A toegang tot alle features -E login/pass van huidige user gebruiken
Write-Host -NoNewline ".NET toegang tot db"
& $aspnet -S $sqlServerName -d $databaseName -A all -E
# FTP toegang tot site , FTP site was manueel aangemaakt in IIS
if (!(Test-Path -path $sitePhysicalPath)) {New-Item $sitePhysicalPath -Type Directory}
& $AppCmd set config "FTP" -section:system.ftpServer/security/authorization /+"[accessType='Allow',users='$teamnaam',permissions='Read, Write']" /commit:apphost

######### open extra ports in firewall
Write-Host -NoNewline "Setting Windows Firewall rules for $teamnaam "
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Projecten-$teamnaam-IN" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=$sitePort
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Projecten-$teamnaam-OUT" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=$sitePort
```

Comment: 1. don't use 2008; 2. this is a question for serverfault; 3. use Desired State Configuration.

Comment: Obliged to use 2008

Comment: look for a new job, srsly, its 2017 out here. use golden image in that case\sql + sysprep